# Can an Artificer learn the same infusion more than once?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

The Artificer class's infusions is one of it's main features, and it says this about creating infusions:

> You must touch each of the objects, and each of your infusions can be in only one object at a time

So, I can only infuse one item with one learned infusion. However, nowhere does it explicitly say that I can't learn the same infusion twice. So the question is, by this reading, can I learn the same infusion twice, and use it on two different objects by doing so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Only Replicate Magic Item can be learned multiple times

The [Infusions list](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#ArtificerInfusions-1131764) includes this sentence in its intro:

> Unless an infusion’s description says otherwise, you can’t learn an infusion more than once.

The only infusion that "says otherwise" is Replicate Magic Item, which says:

> You can learn this infusion multiple times; each time you do so, choose a magic item that you can make with it, picking from the Replicable Items tables below.

Interestingly, it doesn't say you have to choose a *different* magic item each time, so it seems that you could indeed learn to infuse multiples of the same magic item from this table.

Comment: Ah, I had missed that line while reading the initial description of the infusions. Thank you for finding this.